# LDAP Filter, search contains (Active Directory)

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want find users from active directory where Objectsid = "x-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-11060"

My search filter is :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(Objectsid=*11060))
```

but no users are returned.

What is problem with my filter?

When I completely write Objectsid the user information return.

Even when change code to

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(Objectsid=*))
```

that should return all users, but no user are returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is **case-sensitive**, and the proper spelling of that attribute you're trying to use is `objectSid` (not `Objectsid`) - so try this filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(objectSid=*))
```